# What's the best way to use dynamic background in React?

Tags: reactjs, background, inline-styles

I need to be able to switch background images AND apply effects: blur, background color and opacity.

I'm able to swich images (from Header) but when I'm applying effects they overlap above everything - Header, Footer, text ...

[image]

App.js

```
const App = ()=> {
  const [url, setUrl] = useState("kitchenBG.jpg");
  const [color, setColor] = useState("blue");
  const [blur, setBlur] = useState(false);

      return (
      <div style = {{ background: `${color}`,        
                   backgroundImage: `url("${url}")`, 
                   backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat", 
                   backgroundSize: 'cover', 
                   opacity: `${blur}`
                   }}>
          <Router > 
            <Header url={setUrl} color={setColor} blur ={setBlur}/>
                <Routes>
                  <Route exact path="/video" element={<Video/>}></Route>
                  <Route exact path="/" element={<Main/>}></Route>
                  <Route exact path="/audio" element={<Audio/>}></Route>
                  <Route exact path="/climate" element={<Climate/>}></Route>
                  <Route exact path="/floorheat" element={<Floorheat/>}></Route>
                  <Route exact path="/lights" element={<Lights/>}></Route>
                  <Route exact path="/shades" element={<Shades/>}></Route>
                </Routes>
              <Footer />
          </Router> 
      </div>
    );
  }
```